# Zero Vector, and Negative Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

i'm not sure if the title of this question is stated properly but I'll try my best to explain what im asking.

Essentially, I was wondering how we could find the zero vector and the negative vector of some vector u in a vector space V. For example, this question was in my text book.

[image: Textbook Image]

In this case, the zero vector was given as (-1,-1), is there any way you can find it for without being told?

[image]

This was a different question, and I was wondering what the zero vector and negative vector for this would be?

Along with this, how can I find the vector -u? is it always just the scalar multiple -1 with u (which I doubt).  As you can see I'm not very knowledgeable in linear algebra, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: By definition, $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{u}\phantom{x}\forall\phantom{x}\mathbf{u}\in V$. Just use the addition operator given to you and you can obtain the zero vector.

Comment: Question 2 is actually abstract algebra, not linear algebra. "Linear algebra" requires that the axioms of vector spaces hold. In that case, yes, $-\mathbf u = -1\mathbf u$. But these operations do not satisfy the axioms of a vector space, so no, you cannot rely on that equation being true. How you find $-u$ is exactly like how Reza Adrian Tanuharja explained how to find $\bf 0$. Given $\mathbf u = (u_1, u_2)$, what $v_1,v_2$ gives a vector $\bf v$ such that $\mathbf u + \mathbf v = \bf 0$?